# Automatically update references visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, reference, class-library

I have a solution with a class library.

And then I have another solution with a web application which uses the dll above.

Everytime i make some changes on the class library I have to go to web application, remove the class library reference and add it again.

Is it possible to get this done automatically?

Comment: You can put the class library project into your web application solution and then add a reference (Solution reference) to the project which will automatically be updated when generating the web application project